# What's the difference between creating a new terminal tab and creating a new session?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have installed [Tilix](https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/) and I see two different buttons at the top.
**Create a new session** and **Add Terminal Right**. What is the difference between the two?
I am the only user on the system.

I apologise if the question is too naive.

Edit - I have got the Answer from [raj](https://askubuntu.com/users/1089525/raj) and have no more confusions.

Comment: @guiverc I have changed the tag.

Comment: That app has its own web site. https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/faq

Answer (score 0):

When you have a lot of tabs, even 2 tabs, can not see your commands in separate windows and you have to change the tabs with and alt+1 , alt+2 and ...
But when you open a new window, you can arrange them visually and view them all at once.
for example you can not see the tabs on two monitors, but you can move the windows anywhere :)
When you try to detach tabs, they actually become a new window :)

have a great day !

Comment: Can those two terminals conflict each other? Suppose I am installing a package in one and in other I want to install another package, will it conflict?

Comment: No
They don't.
Each executes its own commands.
If you receive an error, write it down.

Comment: @soubhiksen It does not depend on how terminal windows are arranged. It depends on the program/command you want to run. If two instances can be run simultaneously, then there is no problem. In case of installation, generally you can't run two programs that install/remove packages at once, regardless of how you run them.

Comment: Running two programs at the same time is different with two tabs or two terminal windows!
If you enter the code [Visual Studio code for example!] in two terminal windows opens the program for you ,twice!